# React Router V4 allow only certain parameters in URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using the React Router V4 and I've this router's configuration:

```
  <Router history={customHistory}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`/:lng?`} component={Page} />
      <Route path={`/:lng?/firstUrl`} component={Page}/>
      <Route path={`/:lng?/secondUrl`} component={Page}/>
      <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

The `lng` is optional language parameter which should match pattern like a `en`, `de` or absent.
For instance app utilizes these routes:

```
www.website.com/en
www.website.com/en/
www.website.com/  - will load default lang
www.website.com  - will load default lang
www.website.com/de
www.website.com/de/
```

Also I've additional component inside which I define routes for functions:

```
  <ModalRoute component={SomeURL} path={`/:lng?/SomeURL`} parentPath={`/${lang}/`} />
  <ModalRoute component={SomeURL2} path={`/:lng?/SomeURL2`} parentPath={`/${lang}/`} />
```

So as the result I would like to achieve that only allowed language codes (and empty param) would be accepted and which don't - would be redirected to `NoMatch` component.

Is it possible? How it could be achieved?
Example much appreciated

Comment: Route pattern matching is in on-going development: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3105

Comment: One and half year passed since last discussion... haven't understood is this feature currently in progress or forgotten

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use regex in your path.

For a required parameter with specified options:

```
<Route path="/about/:lang(en|de)/" exact component={About}/>
```

For an optional paramater:

```
<Route path="/about/:lang?/" exact component={About}/>
```

For an optional parameter with specified options

```
<Route path="/about/:lang(en|de)?/" exact component={About}/>
```

For [further reading](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/391)

Comment: I've made this in such way: `<Route exact path={/:lng?(en|de)} component={Page} /> <Route path={/:lng?(en|de)/someURL1} component={Page}/>`
But I have two issues: the plain address is not accepted: www.website.com(/) and `lang` paramter somehow stopped detecting `this.props.match.params.lng`. Now it's `undefined`

Comment: I can get `this.props.match.params`, can you post only the <Route/> code?

Comment: The **index.js**:`
          <Router history={customHistory}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={`/:lng?(en|de)`} component={Page} />
              <Route path={`/:lng?(en|de)/url1`} component={Page}/>
              <Route path={`/:lng?(en|de)/url2`} component={Page}/>
              <Route path={`/:lng?(en|de)/url3`} component={Page}/>
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
`  and in **Page.js** the `this.props.match.params.lng` is  **undefined** while without `regex` expression it extracts the lang param from URL

Comment: What is the __?__ for? I mean in here `/:lng?(en|de)`

Comment: the `?` sign means, that **lng** is optional parameter. So it will utilize these routes, which I've described in my question: `www.website.com/en
www.website.com/en/
www.website.com/  - will load default lang, and it is valid, as '?' is used
www.website.com  - will load default lang, and it is valid, as '?' is used
www.website.com/de
www.website.com/de/`

Comment: write it like this `/about/:lng(en|de)?`

Comment: Glad I could help :)